# removing the extra space when setting the height of xap object in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, html, css, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I am hosting the silverlight xap object in aspx page. The aspx page contains two `<div>`.
In the first `<div>` i am having the html menu and in the second `<div>` i am having the xap. I gave height=95%; for xap object, so that the content is occupying the exact browser space but the scroll bar appears with height of some 30px more area(html area) at bottom region. How to remove the scroll bar and the extra area?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need the `<html>` tag to have the style "height:100%;overflow:hidden" and the `<body>` tag to have the style "height:100%;overflow:hidden;margin:0px".  This assumes your two divs a direct children of the body.  The `<object>` tag of the silverlight plugin should have height:100% as well.

The two divs should have height 5% and 95% respectively and both ought to have overflow:hidden as well.